# Почему переменная меняет значение на другое?

Tags: php

Можете объяснить, почему при первой итерации в условии if, после прохождения данного условия, переменная $current принимает значение 1, вместо того, чтобы принять значение 10? Ведь в скобках (if) мы описываем условие, при котором выполнится код, а не присваиваем значение переменной

```
function isContinuousSequence($arr)
{
    $i = 0;
    
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $current = $value;
        $next = $arr[$i + 1];
        if ($next - $current = 1) {
            $i++;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isContinuousSequence([10, 11, 12, 14]);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

`=` - присваивание

а `==` - сравнение

Вывод:

нужно `$next - $current == 1`